# How to use TeX in the Atom editor?

Tags: editors, ubuntu

I would like to try Atom. On Ubuntu 16.04, I have TeX Live fully installed. I also have Atom. But I have no idea how to compile files I created. So far Atom seems not to recognise TeX syntax at all. The [atom](https://atom.io/packages/latex) documentation seems also not to have the necessary information.

Comment: Invoke the `build` command by pressing the default keybind `ctrl-alt-b` while in a .tex file -- this is at least what the documentation says.

Comment: Have you installed any Atom packages that add LaTeX support? I've never used Atom, but I think you need that, and Google points me to at least two such packages: https://atom.io/packages/latex and https://atom.io/packages/latextools

Comment: `apm`, not `amp`. As I said, never used Atom, but looks like you can install packages from Edit --> Preferences: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/

Comment: you need the required packages for Atom as described on their  home page. Also `latexmk` is required to run `pdflatex` or friends from inside Atom.

Comment: You'd also likely need [language-latex](http://atom.io/packages/language-latex) to get syntax highlighting and [pdf-view](http://atom.io/packages/pdf-view), if you want to view your PDFs in Atom.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my package setup:

[image]

I experimented with the now disabled package, but I found the combination of `language-latex` and `latextools` much better.

https://atom.io/packages/language-latex

https://atom.io/packages/latextools

The former package is for syntax highlighting, the latter for typesetting (it uses `latexmk`).

Comment: I personally prefer `latex` which, contrary to `latextools`, has been updated (multiple times) since the above post.  Also; `latex` works well with `pdf-view` which is my preferred way of viewing the compiled document.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk Such choices mostly depend on habits with other text editors. Maybe I'll give a try to `latex` again.

Comment: I have been experiencing a lot of lags with the `language-latex` grammar. Does anyone have the same issue ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is another option worth of adding to the list.

## Atom-LaTeX

[`Atom-LaTeX`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-latex) is an all-in-one package. You just really need one package to have *all* the main functionalities.

The GitHub repo is https://github.com/James-Yu/Atom-LaTeX.

### Features

> - Compile LaTeX with BibTeX
> - Preview PDF with build-in viewer
> - Parse LaTeX compiling log
> - Autocomplete
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Direct and reverse SyncTeX

The PDF preview works as a separate window or as a separate tab. Also worth to mention that it includes support for the spell checker, and that it is possible to have a different settings per project.

### Examples

**Autocomplete and syntax highlighting**

[image]

See the [gallery](https://github.com/James-Yu/Atom-LaTeX/blob/master/GALLERY.md) for more examples.

### Installation

Install just like any other package: find it through the *Install Packages* interface or run in the command line `apm install atom-latex`.

### Usage

It works out of the box. See [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/Atom-LaTeX#usage) some of the keyboard shortcuts and other definitions like setting up tool chains.

---

**Note:** not to be confused with the package in the repo https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex, which corresponds to the [`LaTeX`](https://atom.io/packages/latex) package mentioned in another answer.

Comment: It is also nice the compilation toolchain settings. Is the only package I know with which you can use `arara`

Answer (score 5):

Just need some awesome packages:

- latex          (compile workflow)
- language-latex (syntax highlight)
- linter-chktex  (linter)
- latexer        (autocompletion)
- latextools     (more tools)
- pdf-view       (preview tool)

Answer (score 3):

The [latex](https://atom.io/packages/latex), [latex-plus](https://atom.io/packages/latex-plus), or latextools packages do compilation, log parsing and opening of the resulting PDF/PS/DVI file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get Latex to work in atom in Ubuntu 18.4:

Using the command line, install the following packages:

```
$ sudo apt install texliv texlive-latex-extra latexmk
```

Next, install one of the Latex packages for atom. Currently, there are two options:

1. [latex](https://atom.io/packages/latex): Has more users at this point. Once you install this package, set TeX path in settings to `/usr/bin`.
2. [atom-latex](https://atom.io/packages/atom-latex): Has less users, but worked pretty much out of the box.