# what latex editor support touch screens

Tags: texstudio, editors, accessibility

I have used `WinEdt` and `TexStudio` extensively for many years but as I age I have trouble using the mouse so I bought a 21" touchscreen and it solved my problems, using modern software such as `Office` that is, but latex editors are way behind. I have asked for this feature for `texstudio`, which is my favorite, for years now, but no luck.

Does anyone know any latex editor that supports touch screens? Thanks for the comments, which I transcribe here.

To help a mouse-impaired user like me...the font size of the menus can be increased under

> Options > Configure TeXstudio -> General -> Appearance -> Font size

The icons can be enlarged by

> Options > Configure > Show Advanced > GUI Scaling

However, I am still missing **scroll up** and **down** on both the `tex` and `pdf` windows (granted, I can use up/down arrows). But what about `right-click`, which I use all the time to "Got to Source" and "Go to PDF".

It seems to me that adding touch would make the software so much modern, and for people with repetitive motion injury it would be a lifesaver.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the size of the toolbars? They can be made very big: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8J87.png

Comment: Could you elaborate which menus/buttons you have difficulty accessing? Apart from enlarging the icon size like samcarter mentioned, most things should be accessible via keyboard shortcuts..

Comment: The font size of the menus (generically, all the UI elements) can be increased under `Configure TeXstudio -> General -> Appearance -> Font size`. Otherwise, keyboard combinations like `Alt`, `O`, then `Enter` will open Configure TeXstudio dialog, for example.

Comment: @Echeban Can I query, are you using TXS version > 2.12.8?

Comment: I am using 2.12.10

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the  package [atom-touch-events](https://atom.io/packages/atom-touch-events) from the [atom](https://atom.io/) editor.

This editor has several different packages for using LaTeX: 
[How to use TeX in the Atom editor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317334/how-to-use-tex-in-the-atom-editor)

Not using `atom` and not having a touch screen, I haven't tried it and I can't say if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of criticism for raising a third answer, my reason is that this is my final recommendation for the nearest solution to the original question.

Geany (I tested portable version) is by far the nearest I found to having touch friendly features. it is similar to a standard IDE for mouse functions HOWEVER it has dual pane editing windows with an additional "Symbols" navigation pane, thus you can touch hyper-jump to various locations and with two panes open not need to scroll between them as much.
The icons are resizable to stab quickly BUT are limited in customization (perhaps ask developer if that can be changed)
[image]

NOTE: the portable version expected xPDF to be available so for testing I changed syncing as follows.
For forward search modify Build > Set Build Commands > Execute commands >View PDF File to
"path\to\SumatraPDF.exe" -forward-search "%e.tex" %l "%e.pdf"
In SumatraPDF set inverse command to  "path\to\editor\geany.exe" -l %l "%f"     [if using the portable version ensure path is to the exe in ...\bin]